# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.R$layout

Tags: android, static-libraries, noclassdeffounderror, slidingmenu

I am facing problem **NoClassDefFoundError** in sliding menu (third party library) in **below 5.0**

**Above 5.0** works perfect ..

I m *goggling* past day's **sliding menu library** related in **stack-overflow** and  it's **git-hub** forum but can't get exact solution so please help me...!

**Error-Log**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.R$layout
>               at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityHelper.onCreate(SlidingActivityHelper.java:45)
>               at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onCreate(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:23)
>               at com.festevo.devtesting.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:26)
>               at com.festevo.devtesting.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:126)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 22
        versionName "2.6.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
//        jumboMode = true
//
//        // Avoid the OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded:
//        incremental true
//        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotifysdk:1.0.0-beta6@aar'
    compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotifysdk:1.0.0-beta8@aar'
    // NOTE: Version must match!
    compile project('libraries:FacebookSDK')
    compile project('libraries:simple-crop-image-lib')
    compile project('libraries:SlidingMenu')
    compile project('libraries:nineoldandroids')
    compile project('libraries:google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':ffmpeg4android_lib')
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude module: 'gson'
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
//include ':app'
include ':app:libraries:FacebookSDK', ':pdf'
include ':app:libraries:simple-crop-image-lib'
include ':app:libraries:SlidingMenu'
include ':app:libraries:SlidingMenu:libraries:ActionaBarSherLockLibrary'
include ':app:libraries:nineoldandroids'
include ':app:libraries:google-play-services_lib'
include ':ffmpeg4android_lib'
```

Comment: can post your error log and the code you facing issue. Above 5 its work so we \want to see your code

Comment: in which activity code i m showing?? when i am clicking on skip button then suddenly crash application generate error